# Loading a 32bit .so library in a 64bit JVM

Tags: java, cpu-architecture, dynamic-loading, .so

We are developing a Java application to be run on Linux environments (Ubuntu for now) which communicates with a piece of hardware. Said hardware uses a .so library made available by the manufacturer for x86 architectures only.

The thing is, we would very much like to run this on a 64bit JVM. Loading the library in a x86 JVM works fine but we cannot load on the 64bit version. So, besides switching to a x86 JVM, are there any other ways to make this lib available to my 64 bit Java application? Is it possible, for instance, for me to write another os wrapper library in x64 that, in turn calls the x86 version so the JVM can load my 64 bit wrapper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You can not load a 32-bit library into the address space of a 64-bit process.

Comment: The only way I can come up with to use the 32 bit code is to have another process (32 bit) that communicates with the hardware and an IPC mechanism set up between that process and the 64 bit JVM.  Not trivial but certainly possible.

Comment: @JJF - Even doing that would be complicated likely to the point of impossibility by any potential side effects.  The native 32-bit code can modify Java object(s) or state(s), or can be effected by them, and those wouldn't necessarily exist in the separate 32-bit JVM, and it would be almost impossible to propagate any side effects back to the 64-bit JVM.  And some things can't be easily passed to a child process, if they can be passed at all - such as open sockets or files.

Comment: I agree it's not trivial depending on a lot of factors though I don't get the impression the OP's library interacts with the Java side.  Sounds like a comm interface to the device.   Myself and folks I work with have done this many times.  Shuffle off device I/O to a separate process.  If it's a data in <-> data out type of interface it shouldn't be to difficult to move the data between the two processes.

Answer (score 1):

with this code you can check if you are on a 64bit pc and load the lybrary:

```
boolean is64bit = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("64");
if(is64bit){
   try {
       System.load("64Bit ibrary");
   } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
   }
else{
   try {
        System.load("32Bit ibrary");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
}
```